# python screenshoot save files name change

Tags: python

How do I have to code it like I want to make new png file?
When I press "P" save the png file name as "A(number)".

```py
import time
import pyautogui as pag
import keyboard

A = 0

while True:  # making a loop
    try:  # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.read_key() == "p":  # if key 'q' is pressed 

            myScreenshot = pag.screenshot()
            myScreenshot.save(r'C:\Users\Users\Desktop\"A".png') #name as "A".png 
            time.sleep(1)
            A = A+1
            
            break  # finishing the loop
    except:
        break  # if user pressed a key other than the given key the loop will break
```

Comment: Use three backticks ``` before and after your code block

Answer (score 1):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to have the variable `A` be part of the string.

```py
myScreenshot.save(fr'C:\Users\Users\Desktop\"A({A})".png')
```

For `A = 0`, this would result in the filename being `"A(0)".png`